# What is the correct way to implement a context manager in psycopg2?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I've been refactoring my psycopg2 code using functions, previously I had it all on a try-except-finally block, however I'm not quite sure how to implement a context-manager to handle the connection and cursor. My SQL queries work and look like this:

```
def random_query(schema, table, username, number_of_files):
    random_query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} WHERE username = {username} ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT {limit}").format(
        schema=sql.Identifier(schema),
        table=sql.Identifier(table),
        username=sql.Literal(username),
        limit=sql.Literal(number_of_files)
        )
    cursor.execute(random_query)
    return cursor.fetchone()

def insert_query(schema, table, values):
    insert_query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {schema}.{table}(shortcode, username, filename, extension) VALUES ({shortcode}, {username}, {filename}, {extension})").format(
        schema=sql.Identifier(schema),
        table=sql.Identifier(table),
        shortcode=sql.Literal(values[0]),
        username=sql.Literal(values[1]),
        filename=sql.Literal(values[2]),
        extension=sql.Literal(values[3])
        )
    cursor.execute(insert_query)
    conn.commit()
```

1. First version:

```
@contextmanager
def get_connection():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**DB_CONNECTION)
    try:
        yield connection
    except Exception as err:
        connection.rollback()
        print('Error: ', err)
        raise
    finally:
        if (connection):
            connection.close()
            print("Connection is closed.")

@contextmanager
def get_cursor(connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        yield cursor
    finally:
        cursor.close()

with get_connection() as conn, get_cursor(conn) as cursor:
    random_record = random_query('test_schema', 'test_table', 'username', 1)
    insert_query('test_schema', 'test_table2', random_record)
```

2. Second version:

```
@contextmanager
def sql_connection():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**DB_CONNECTION)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        yield connection,cursor
    except Exception as err:
        connection.rollback()
        print('Error : ', err)
        raise
    finally:
        if (connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("Connection is closed")

with sql_connection() as (conn, cursor):
    random_record = random_query('test_schema', 'test_table', 'username', 1)
    insert_query('test_schema', 'test_table2', random_record)
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any difference between the first and the second version? Which one is preferable?
2. As you can see in `insert_query`, there is a line that calls `conn.commit()` From the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html), I understand that this is not necessary if we are using a context manager. Can I remove them?

> Changed in version 2.5: if the connection is used in a with statement,
> the method is automatically called if no exception is raised in the
> with block.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why print the `str()` of the error before you reraise it?

Comment: The documentation says they already implemented a context manager for the connection. What extra functionality are you looking for in implementing new context managers yourself?

Comment: Have you looked at [Usage](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html) *with statement*? To me it looks like you are over complicating this. Since `with connnection` does  not close the connection automatically just declare the connection once and then deal with the case where there is a failure.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's correct, I misunderstood the docs, at the end I used WITH statement as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither version is preferable, you are still over complicating things by duplicating behavior. Per the example here [Connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html):

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(**DB_CONNECTION)

with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(<sql>)

with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(<other_sql>)
```

Committing, rollback on the connection and closing of cursor is done for you. All you have to do is `connection.close()` when you no longer want to use the connection.